# android database connection

Tags: android

hi i am developing one simple application for android mobile i created first time it was working but i want crate same thing in other project but i unable to do getting error like unable open database

```
package com.exampleHelloText;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import android.content.Context;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;

public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    //private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.drager/databases/";
    private static String DB_PATH = Environment.getDataDirectory()+"/data/com.exampleHelloText/databases/";
    final static String DB_NAME = "myDBName";
    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase=null;
    private final Context myContext;
    private DataBaseHelper myDbHelper;
    private static String TAG ="MyActivity";

    public DataBaseHelper(Context context){
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
        this.myContext = context;

    }

    public DataBaseHelper createDataBase() throws IOException{
        boolean dbExist =checkDataBase();
        //SQLiteDatabase db_read =null;
        Log.i(TAG,"############value of dbExist"+dbExist+"##########");
        if (dbExist){
            //db must exist
        }
        else{
        myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(myContext);
        myDataBase = myDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        myDataBase.close();
        //this.getReadableDatabase();
            //db_read.close();

            try {
                copyDataBase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new Error("error copying database");
            }
        }
        return this;

    }



    public void copyDataBase() throws IOException{
        // open db as input stream
        InputStream myInput;
        //open empty db as output stream
        OutputStream myOutPut;
        try {
            myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

            //path to newly created db
            String outFileName =DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

            myOutPut = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

            //transfer bytes from the inputFile to the outPutFile
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
                myOutPut.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            myOutPut.flush();
            myOutPut.close();
            myInput.close();
            }
        catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }




    }

    private boolean checkDataBase() {
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

        try {
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        } catch (SQLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }

        if (checkDB != null){
            checkDB.close();
        }
        return true;
        //return checkDB !=null ? true : false;
    }

    public void openDataBase()throws SQLException{
        //open the database
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close(){
        if(myDataBase != null){
            myDataBase.close();
        }
        super.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

please help me
thanks in advance

Comment: Your code would demand that copyDataBase() is run first.. is it? Have you verified that the database actually exists at the specified location? It would also help to see the code where you are triggering the error. Do you have a stack trace? Also, to get a databaseobject in openDatabase(), you could call myDbHelper.getWritableDatabase() to get a SQLiteDatabase object.

Answer (score 0):

You have empty body of **onCreate** and **onUpgrade** methods.
Make sure that you're invoking your method createDataBase() and getting database through myDataBase.

Comment: But he does have a copyDatabase() method, in which he is copying an existing database. If he's actually running that method is currently not easy to tell.

Comment: I accepted that he is using standard methods. But you have right, my assumption is not right.

Answer (score 0):

For Database you can refer [this](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html).. download the Zip file...